# FQL multiquery for a single request

Tags: android, facebook-fql

I currently have 2 FQL queries, one which retrieves messages from the newsfeed and another which retrieves users uid and name from their actor_id. The issue is that these queries are being run in separate requests and therefore they are out of sync with eachother.

I am trying to join the two queries into one so that i have a single JSON object and can parse all of the data at once.

I followed this question as a starter:
[FQL query to get the Immediate family (name, birthday and relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965159/fql-query-to-get-the-immediate-family-name-birthday-and-relationship)
However I have been unable to figure out how to make this work with my queries.

My two queries are:
String fqlQuery = "SELECT post_id, created_time, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE type = 'newsfeed' AND uid=me()) ORDER BY created_time";

String fqlFriendInfo = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE type = 'newsfeed' AND uid=me()) ORDER BY created_time)";

So really I want to join these two queries so that I have the uid and name, along with the post_id and message related to that user from a single FQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
{"query1":"SELECT post_id, created_time, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE type = 'newsfeed' AND uid=me()) ORDER BY created_time", "query2":"SELECT id, name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1)"}
```

Please use profile table instead of user table, because the second query is most likely failed(return empty result for some actor_id). Your first query's actor_id can be a page id but uid is means a user, not a page.

Comment: Great answer thanks! and thanks for the profile table tip, that helped me to fix another bug too!